# Getting Not Found when using Flask in my Python script for Spotify authorization

Tags: python, heroku, oauth, flask, spotify

I'm trying to upload my Python script to authorize the user for the Spotify iOS SDK. Honestly, I dont know what I'm doing but the documentation is really poor. I'm using Heroku as web server but when I use `foreman start` I only get this on localhost:5000:

```
Not Found
The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.
```

spotify_token_swap.py looks as following:

```
import cherrypy
from cherrypy import tools
import simplejson as json
import requests
import os
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

# CHANGE these values to your own
k_client_id = "spotify-ios-sdk-beta"
k_client_secret = "ba95c775e4b39b8d60b27bcfced57ba473c10046"
k_client_callback_url = "spotify-ios-sdk-beta://callback"

verbose = True

class SpotifyTokenSwap(object):
    @cherrypy.expose
    @tools.json_out()
    def swap(self, code=None):
        params = {
            'grant_type': 'authorization_code',
            'client_id': k_client_id,
            'client_secret': k_client_secret,
            'redirect_uri': k_client_callback_url,
            'code' : code
        }
        r = requests.post('https://ws.spotify.com/oauth/token', params)
        cherrypy.response.status = r.status_code
        if verbose:
            print
            print code
            print r.status_code
            print r.text
            print
        return r.json()

def CORS():
    cherrypy.response.headers["Access-Control-Allow-Origin"] = "*"


if __name__ == '__main__':
    cherrypy.tools.CORS = cherrypy.Tool('before_handler', CORS)
    root = SpotifyTokenSwap()

    config = {
        'global' : {
            'server.socket_host' : '0.0.0.0',
            'server.socket_port' : 5000,
            'server.thread_pool' : 10,
        # 'environment' : 'production',
        },
        '/' : {
            'tools.CORS.on' : True,
    }
    }
    cherrypy.quickstart(root, '/', config=config)
```

and I start the foreman webserver using this in my Procfile:

```
web: gunicorn spotify_token_swap:app
```

Comment: I am so very confused as to what you are trying to do. You shouldn't post secret keys and your callback looks ... wrong. You shouldn't be mixing cherrypy and flask. I mean you could, but why would you do that?

Comment: So if I removed the Flask code, how would I then start the service from the Procfile? I only get Not Found on page.

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure you are pointing to the wrong wsgi application. Pointing to app from the Procfile meant that flask was serving the page. You registered and built everything with cherrypy, and did not include any routes in flask. So the app object had no routes, ie no '/'. So you need to switch to serving the cherrypy app.

Since you're removing the flask app part, you should remove the `if __name__ == '__main__':` line and change the rest to

```
config = {
    'global' : {
        'server.socket_host' : '0.0.0.0',
        'server.socket_port' : 5000,
        'server.thread_pool' : 10,
    # 'environment' : 'production',
    },
    '/' : {
        'tools.CORS.on' : True,
    }
}
wsgiapp = cherrypy.Application(SpotifyTokenSwap(), '/', config=config)
```

And then use this in the ProcFile

```
web: gunicorn spotify_token_swap:wsgiapp
```

I'm not used to Foreman or cherrypy, but I think this is what you need to do.

Comment: Thanks for your help! When I acces localhost I only get this error `500 Internal Server Error
The server encountered an unexpected condition which prevented it from fulfilling the request. File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cherrypy/_cprequest.py", line 647, in respond
    self.namespaces(self.config)` . Any idea what that could be?

Comment: It means that it cannot understand one of the configuration options. Try taking out the `tools.CORS.on` config option first. If it loads the page or gives you some other error, we've got another problem.

Comment: Ok I got another error now `NotFound: (404, "The path '/' was not found.")`

Comment: Oh, try changing the `@cherrypy.expose` decorator in SpotifyTokenSwap to `@cherrypy.expose(alias='/')`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this python service instead:

1. Download Google App engine [here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstartedpython27/introduction)
2. Install the launcher
3. Go to [ChirsmLarssons GitHub](https://github.com/chrismlarson/spotify-token-swap-gae) and download the project, it will have everything you need.
4. In Google app engine launcher, Press add excisting project
5. Go Google app engines website and create a project, here you will get an app-id
6. in app.yaml , replace spotifyauth with the app-id
7. Press deploy
8. Done, you can now access it on the web at app-id.appspot.com/swap

Before I got this solution, I've spend hours in the jungle of Python and Ruby, Cheers!